# Display iTunes INSIDE a UIWebView on iOS iPhone & iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, https, uiwebview, itunes

I have searched high & low for the answer to this. The closest answers describe how to have iTunes launched in the Safari app instead of having the iTunes app launched when trying to open an iTunes url inside a UIWebView. I want to stay in my UIWebView & have the itunes website display inside it. Here is the call;

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/gb/artist/SOME_ARTIST/id_etc_etc"];

self.webView.delegate = self;

NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Using the UIWebView Delegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

I can see that Apple is changing the https:// request to an itmss:// request.

How can I get around this to open iTunes INSIDE the UIWebView?

Using SKStoreProductViewController is not an option either.

I have also tried solutions that suggest changing the device type in the USerDefaults with no avail;

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"some old phone or other" forKey:@"UserAgent"]];
```

After a lot of googling on the subject, it seems like I'm the only one in history who has ever wanted to do this. Surely not:) There must be someone who knows a filthy hack for achieving what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why would you want to open iTunes inside of a WebView as opposed to the iTunes application itself?

Comment: To keep the user inside the app, maintaining the self-contained user experience.

Comment: @GeoffH I must be the 2nd one in history who wants to do this =) Did you ever find a solution?